# AutoComplete using JQuery in GridView

Tags: c#, jquery, autocomplete

AutoComplete using JQuery in GridView. I want to autocomplete functionality in gridview which is required for bulk update

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like:

```
jQuery("*[@id$=theGridId] input[@id$=textBoxId]").autocomplete(list)
```

to attach the jquery autocomplete to all textboxes (input html controls) with the id  textBoxId inside your grid.

The elem[@id$=someID] means all tags named 'elem' with the id atribute ending in 'someID'.

This is required because asp.net will change the client id of tags so if you use something like:

```
<asp:TextBox id="myTextBox" />
```

the page will contain something like:

```
<input type="textbox" id="ctl00_otherName_myTextBox" />
```

You need to be aware that using the grid view for bulk update has some serious limitations; most likely the page size will just be too big if you add a couple of validations to the grid input...

Comment: Thank you, this helped me add autocomplete in a datagrid.